# How to remove Inf values from a matrix retaining its size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have got a matrix in a loop which is

```
m=


 -132.5901    -137.2695   -114.1264   -131.4986   -134.5733       Inf
       Inf       Inf       Inf        -135.2631   -121.7322       -119.7471
 -132.7978    -123.8068   -135.9385       Inf      -134.1602     -117.6997
 -130.1930    -134.0093   -137.4125   -128.7641       Inf        -116.0473
```

I want a command which can be used in loop to get the answer as:

```
 -132.5901 -137.2695 -114.1264 -131.4986 -134.5733  -119.7471  
 -132.7978 -123.8068 -135.9385 -135.2631 -121.7322  -117.6997
 -130.1930 -134.0093 -137.4125 -128.7641 -134.1602  -116.0473
```

I don't want a single vector using isfinite command. The matrix size should be retained automatically using Matlab.

Comment: The matrix size is NOT retained in the example you provide in the question. So you need to provide more info. How do you want the size retained? Should we pad each column with `NaN` at the bottom? Also, the question implies that we might expect there to only be one `Inf` per column? Is this really the case? If so, then a simple call to `isfinite` and then `reshape` will do the trick (being sure to manually add in the bottom row of NaNs). The devil of any question is in the details!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that in retaining the size of the original matrix, you want us to pad the bottom of the solution matrix with `NaN`. I'm also going to assume that there might be more than one `Inf` in any given column. In that case the following loop-based solution works for me:

```
%# Set up an example matrix
M = [Inf 2 Inf 4; 5 Inf 6 7; Inf Inf 8 Inf];
[T, N] = size(M);

%# Get an index of finite elements
I1 = isfinite(M);

%# Solution 1
Soln1 = NaN(T, N);
for n = 1:N
    CurCol = M(:, n);
    Soln1(1:sum(I1(:, n)), n) = CurCol(I1(:, n));
end
```

There is probably a fully-vectorized solution to this problem for the general case (there definitely is - see my update below). However, I'd be surprised if it yields much of a speed-up over the loop-based solution. Single loops are now very fast in Matlab IF you set your problem up so you can operate on the columns of a matrix (as opposed to the rows), since these elements are allocated sequentially in memory.

Now, let us assume that there is only one `Inf` per column. In this case, the problem is much easier to solve, and can be done with the following one-liner:

```
%# Solution 2
Soln2 = [reshape(M(isfinite(M)), T-1, N); NaN(1, N)];
```

Solution 2 will obviously fail for the example matrix I set up, since 6 elements can not be re-arranged into a T-1 by N (ie 2 by 4) matrix.

**UPDATE:** Okay, so for no good reason, it was annoying me that I couldn't do it without a loop. Thus, here is a loop-less solution:

```
%# Solution 3
Soln3 = NaN(T, N);
I2 = bsxfun(@plus, cumsum(isfinite(M)), (0:T:T*(N-1)));
I2 = I2(:);
I2(I1 == 0) = [];
Soln3(I2) = M(isfinite(M));
```

Quick (very) non-rigorous speed test on loop versus non-loop solution:

```
Elapsed time is 0.203997 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.251969 seconds.
```

The non-loop solution will probably improve (relatively speaking) though if `M` is bigger.

Now I need to get back to work :-)

Comment: Very nice solution :) Why `m(~isinf(m))` won't give good results?

Comment: @MarounMaroun The OP stated that the solution needed to retain the size of the original matrix. Your solution, `m(~isinf(m))` yields a column vector, not a matrix. Of course, applying `reshape` to your `m(~isinf(m))` may yield a matrix of the right size, BUT only if there is only one `Inf` per column. I'm about to update my answer to reflect this actually... Cheers.

Comment: @AsthaSharma No probs, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Colin's answer:

```
>> M = [Inf 2 Inf 6; 5 Inf 8 4; Inf Inf 7 Inf];
>> [N,I] = sort(M)
N =
     5     2     7     4
   Inf   Inf     8     6
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
I =
     2     1     3     2
     1     2     2     1
     3     3     1     3
```

So that `N` is already a possible end-product.

The data in `N` are *sorted*, so if you don't want that, you'll have to un-sort:

```
>> for ii = 1:size(M,2)        
>>     N(~isinf(N(:,ii)),ii) = M(~isinf(M(:,ii)),ii);
>> end
N =
     5     2     8     6
   Inf   Inf     7     4
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
```

And, if you really must get rid of the `inf`, just issue a

```
N(isinf(N)) = NaN;
```

somewhere along the lines (and/or replace `isinf` with `isnan` where needed).

Comment: Very neat +1. I know it is a bad habit to be obsessed with getting rid of single loops from solutions - since the speed gains are often marginal (and sometimes negative), but none-the-less I've updated my answer to provide a loop-less solution :-)